# Can matter be super-compressed by a magnetic field

Tags: black-holes, faster-than-light, electromagnetism

So I had this idea for an FTL drive that would work by creating a rift (a black hole before it tugs on space enough to become unstable and deadly) via an *unbelievably* strong magnetic field. I know that atoms are mostly empty space anyway, and they can be compressed to smaller sizes with a big enough applied force. But could a magnetic field actually produce a force capable of squishing a matter (probably plasma) down to the point where it would become a black hole?

Comment: Someone flagged this off-topic. I voted "leave open", but could you expand it to explain how are you building whole world with this information? I know you mentioned it, but this flag suggests that making it more obvious and visible may be a good idea.

Comment: @Molot It was more of just a quick question on if it was possible to compress matter like this, but I was thinking about using this as a critical piece of tech in a story I'm writing. Aside from FTL travel, it's also important as a plot device since a rift can be destabilized into a black hole (the phrase "every tool can be used as a weapon" comes up a lot in the story)>

Comment: @Mattias Look up Neutron Star. That involves gravity, not magnetism, but you might get some ideas.

Answer (score 4):

Yes.  See for example [The Z Machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z_Pulsed_Power_Facility#Physics_of_the_Z_machine) for ideas.

You can also find videos where a metal object like a coin in crushed using such effects.

Look at the fields involved in [Magnetars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetar), and *that’s* not enough to crush matter beyond nuclear densities.  But using pulsed power, small regions, and *invoking quantum gravity effects* you can get away with it.  Quantum gravity is a big unknown right now, and that gives you room to paint whatever you like without violating the *known* laws of physics.